# Framework for developing web sites using python and eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, web, web-deployment-project

I am participating in a student team and we are going to develop a web-site. I have experience in developing web sites using ASP.Net and C# as codebehind (in visual studio). So basically we were wondering if we can make the same thing but with Eclipse and Python. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's much support you can get from Eclipse for Python web frameworks, with one minor exception: [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) (Python plugin for Eclipse) offers some [basic tools](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_django.html) for [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) framework.

Speaking of frameworks alone, Django is a good one to start with (and it's very popular). If you need more flexibility, you can try [Pyramid](http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), or [Turbo Gears](http://www.turbogears.org/). There are in fact many possibilities, take a look [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks).